# How to Handle Corda Exceptions during RPC call

Tags: java, corda

I have a springboot application which connects to a Corda Node . Whenever I am doing a node connection and do the following `nodeRPCConnection.getProxy().startTrackedFlowDynamic(ExampleFlow.class).getReturnValue().get()`
I need to handle the following

> Unhandled exceptions: java.lang.InterruptedException,
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException

which I am handling through ExceptionHandler. Question is how can I handle Contract Exceptions ? Cause whenever I am triggering a Contract Exception it gets changed to ExecutionException

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Use `flow.returnValue.getOrThrow` instead of `get`, which will unwrap an `ExecutionExceptions` for you are return their cause instead.